# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus confusion

Tags: calculus

I know that $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt = f(x)$.  What about $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x} f(t-x) dt$?  Is that just $f(x-x)$?  I think I have to use the chain rule but I'm not sure how.

Thank you!

Comment: Also, I tried to change my username back to "badatmath" but it didn't work.

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Variable_limits).

Comment: @okay-at-math: I can make that change, if you'd like.

Comment: @ZevChonoles: it's alright, apparently I'm less bad at math than I thought, if the answer is that complicated.

Comment: @RagibZaman: Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is an informal way of figuring out what the answer is. For someone like me who has a limited number of brain cells, it beats trying to remember a formula.

Let $F(u)$ be any antiderivative (indefinite integral) of $f(u)$. Then 
$$\int_0^x f(t-x)\,dt=\left.F(t-x)\right|_0^x=F(0)-F(-x).$$
Now differentiate with respect to $x$. By the definition of antiderivative, we have $F'(u)=f(u)$. Thus, by the Chain Rule, our derivative is $-(-f(-x))$, or more simply $f(-x)$.

Comment: Wow that is clever :D Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be the following:

$$\int\limits_0^x {f\left( {t - x} \right)dt} \overbrace  = ^{t - x = u}\int\limits_{ - x}^0 {f\left( u \right)du}  =  - \int\limits_0^{ - x} {f\left( u \right)du} $$

From this it is immediate that

$$\frac d{dx}\int\limits_0^x {f\left( {x - t} \right)dt}   =-\frac d{dx} \int\limits_0^{-x} {f\left( u \right)du}=f(-x) $$

where the $-$ signs cancelled.

Comment: eh?  How do you get $t-x = 0$?

Comment: @JackPenny It's a typo, it should be $t-x=u$ (a change of variables).